# How to partition table in blocks when value change into one colum in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following query,

```
declare @data as TABLE (one int, two int);
insert into @data (one, two) values (1,1)
insert into @data (one, two) values (2,1)
insert into @data (one, two) values (3,2)
insert into @data (one, two) values (4,2)
insert into @data (one, two) values (5,2)
insert into @data (one, two) values (6,1)
insert into @data (one, two) values (7,1)
insert into @data (one, two) values (8,3)
insert into @data (one, two) values (9,3)
select  one, two,
dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY two ASC) AS BlockNumber --Same dates same number
from @data
order by one
```

with results,

```
one two BlockNumber
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   2   2
4   2   2
5   2   2
6   1   1
7   1   1
8   3   3
9   3   3
```

I would however like the following result,

```
one two BlockNumber
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   2   2
4   2   2
5   2   2
6   1   3**
7   1   3**
8   3   4**
9   3   4**
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: This will run on both a 2008 and 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do it with the analytic functions from before SQL 2012 - there may be some Laggy goodness but I'm not that comfortable with those functions yet.

So, if the priority is the result set rather than how it's produced, I'd use:

```
;With Blocks as (
    select d1.one,d1.two,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d1.one) as BlockNumber
    from @data d1
        left join
        @data d2
            on
                d1.two = d2.two and
                d1.one = d2.one + 1
    where d2.one is null
    union all
    select d.one,d.two,b.BlockNumber
    from
        @data d
            inner join
        Blocks b
            on
                d.two = b.two and
                d.one = b.one + 1
) select * from Blocks
order by one
```

The CTE first finds every row which differs from the previous row by its `two` value. We then keep adding any rows which immediately succeed already identified rows and have the same `two` value and assign them the same Block number.

Comment: @entropy - I've had a quick play with them but not thought of anything better yet.

Comment: @entropy - I've got as far as the expression `CASE WHEN LAG(two,1,~two) OVER (ORDER BY one) != two THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` which returns a `1` for the start of each block (rows 1,3,6 and 8) and a `0` otherwise. That could be used to simplify the CTE a bit, but I've not got a complete solution using just the analytics.

Comment: Thanks - if I could I would give you ten votes for this. Read up about CTE now. And seems perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH T1
     AS (SELECT one,
                two,
                dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY one) - 
                dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY two ORDER BY one) AS Grp
         FROM   @data),
     T2
     AS (SELECT *,
                MIN(one) OVER (PARTITION BY Grp) AS MinInGroup
         FROM   T1)
SELECT one,
       two,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MinInGroup) AS BlockNumber
FROM   T2
ORDER  BY one
```